# Filter objects in geojson based on a specific key

Tags: filter, geojson, jq

I try to edit a geojson file to keep only objects that have the key "name". 
The filter works but I can't find a way to keep the other objects and, specifically, the geometry and redirect the whole stuff to a new geojson file. Is there a way to display the whole object after filtering one of its children objects?

Here is an example of my data. The first object has the "name" property and the second hasn't:

```
{
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "way/24824633",
      "properties": {
        "@id": "way/24824633",
        "highway": "tertiary",
        "lit": "yes",
        "maxspeed": "50",
        "name": "Rue de Kleinbettingen",
        "surface": "asphalt"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            5.8997935,
            49.6467825
          ],
          [
            5.8972561,
            49.6467445
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "way/474396855",
      "properties": {
        "@id": "way/474396855",
        "highway": "path"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            5.8020608,
            49.6907648
          ],
          [
            5.8020695,
            49.6906054
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is what I tried, using **jq**

```
cat file.geojson | jq '.features[].properties | select(has("name"))'
```

The "geometry" is also a child of "features" but I can't find a way to make the selection directly from the "features" level. Is there some way to do that? Or a better path to the solution?

So, the required ouput is:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": "way/24824633",
  "properties": {
    "@id": "way/24824633",
    "highway": "tertiary",
    "lit": "yes",
    "maxspeed": "50",
    "name": "Rue de Kleinbettingen",
    "surface": "asphalt"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        5.8997935,
        49.6467825
      ],
      [
        5.8972561,
        49.6467445
      ]
 ]}}
```

Comment: What is your exact required output/?

Comment: Each object which has a "name" key including its geometry property. Like this one (sorry, bad manipulation so the example is in the comment just below):

Comment: {
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": "way/24824633",
  "properties": {
    "@id": "way/24824633",
    "highway": "tertiary",
    "lit": "yes",
    "maxspeed": "50",
    "name": "Rue de Kleinbettingen",
    "surface": "asphalt"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        5.8997935,
        49.6467825
      ],
      [
        5.8972561,
        49.6467445
      ],

Comment: Also your `JSON` has syntax issues, some unterminated `}` I suppose, check your code in http://jsonlint.com and fix the error seen, then you can use `jq` on it

Comment: Yes it was just an excerpt but I should have added the terminating } (which is indeed in the code) to avoid confusion.

Comment: for `jq` to use used, you need a error free `JSON`

Comment: @Inian  Nevertheless, I followed your advice and validated in jsonlint.com. No problem there.

Comment: @Plouf: I am seeing an error `Error: Parse error on line 39:
...054       ],      }
---------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got '}'`

Comment: @Inian I corrected the error in the "required output" part. Thanks for noticing. I learned something important here: not only check the whole code in jsonlint.com but also the posted excerpts. Won't make this mistake again.

Answer (score 3):

You can [assign](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Assignment) the filtered list back to `.features`:

```
jq '.features |= map(select(.properties|has("name")))'
```

Comment: Glad to hear that!